# SQLite3 split date while creating index

Tags: datetime, indexing, sqlite

I'm using a SQLite3 database, and I have a table that looks like this:

[image: sqlite3 displaying table]

The database is quite big and running queries is very slow. I'm trying to speed up the process by indexing some of the columns. One of the columns that I want to index is the `QUOTE_DATETIME` column.

**Problem:** I want to index by date (YYYY-MM-DD) only, not by date and time (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS), which is the data I currently have in `QUOTE_DATETIME`.

**Question:** How can I use `CREATE INDEX` to create an index that uses only dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD? Should I split `QUOTE_DATETIME` into 2 columns: `QUOTE_DATE` and `QUOTE_TIME`? If so, how can I do that? Is there an easier solution?

Thanks for helping! :D

**Attempt 1:** I tried running `CREATE INDEX id ON DATA (date(QUOTE_DATETIME))` but I got the error `Error: non-deterministic functions prohibited in index expressions`.

**Attempt 2:** I ran `ALTER TABLE data ADD COLUMN QUOTE_DATE TEXT` to create a new column to hold the date only. And then `INSERT INTO data(QUOTE_DATE) SELECT date(QUOTE_DATETIME) FROM data`. The `date(QUOTE_DATETIME)` should convert the date + time to only date, and the `INSERT INTO` should add the new values to `QUOTE_DATE`. However, it doesn't work and I don't know why. The new column ends up not having anything added to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Expression indexes must not use functions that might change their return value based on data not mentioned in the function call itself. The `date()` function is such a function because it might use the current time zone setting.

   However, in SQLite 3.20 or later, you can use `date()` in indexes as long as you are not using any time zone modifiers.
2. INSERT adds new rows. To modify existing rows, use [UPDATE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html):

   ```
   UPDATE Data SET Quote_Date = date(Quote_DateTime);
   ```

Comment: 1. Thanks for the explanation. It might not be a good solution anyways. 2. That worked for me, thanks for explaining why INSERT didn't work!